# How to send email to multiple recipients with drop down list?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to send one email to group of people in `.CC`.

I have one Excel worksheet called "Project" with drop down list which contains contact group names.

Workers 1 shift (address B2), on the other worksheet called "contacts" I have email list in columns with first row of name of above groups (headline address A2:AX2).

I want to choose from the drop down list the email group and send one email to each person on the list. Now I have an Inputbox with range that I have to select manually.

```vb
Sub EmailCC()

    Dim xOTApp As Object
    Dim xMItem As Object
    Dim xCell As Range
    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xEmailAddr As String
    Dim xTxt As String

    On Error Resume Next
    xTxt = ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Address
    Set xRg = Application.InputBox("Address list:", "Range", xTxt, , , , , 8)

    If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Set xOTApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    For Each xCell In xRg
        If xCell.Value Like "*@*" Then
            If xEmailAddr = "" Then
                xEmailAddr = xCell.Value
            Else
                xEmailAddr = xEmailAddr & ";" & xCell.Value
            End If
        End If
    Next

    Set xMItem = xOTApp.CreateItem(0)

    With xMItem
        .To = " "
        .CC = xEmailAddr
        .Display
    End With

End Sub
```

[Excel file with macro example](https://mega.nz/file/oC5SzI6C#TL8ozP9AIugCtniLqn1ps1XN1w1Sj1XkUb8RhpWKCVQ)

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: How to change current macro form pop up message to selecting a contact group from the drop-down list? I hope it is clear now. Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some suggestions:

- Don't use On Error Resume Next unless it's strictly necessary
- Name your variables to something meaningful (use `contactsHeaderRange` instead of `xRG`)
- Comment your code
- Split the code in steps

Read Code's comments and adjust it to fit your needs

EDIT: Changed from one email per address, to all address in one email

```
Public Sub SendEmailsByGroup()
    
    Dim projectSheet As Worksheet
    Set projectSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Project")
    
    Dim groupCell As Range
    Set groupCell = projectSheet.Range("B2")
    
    Dim groupName As String
    groupName = groupCell.Value
    
    Dim contactsSheet As Worksheet
    Set contactsSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Contacts")
    
    Dim contactsHeadersRange As Range
    Set contactsHeadersRange = contactsSheet.Range("A2:C2")
    
    ' Get header according to group name
    Dim contactsGroupHeader As Range
    Set contactsGroupHeader = contactsHeadersRange.Find(groupName)
    
    ' If the group is not found, cancel the process
    If contactsGroupHeader Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Group name not selected or found"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Get group email values from range (use transpose to pass the range to a 1D array)
    Dim groupEmails As Variant
    groupEmails = Application.Transpose(contactsSheet.Range(contactsGroupHeader.Offset(1, 0), contactsSheet.Cells(contactsSheet.Rows.Count, contactsGroupHeader.Column).End(xlUp)).Value)
    
    SendEmails groupEmails
    

End Sub

Private Sub SendEmails(ByVal groupEmails As Variant)

    Dim outlookApp As Object
    Set outlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    
    Dim mailItem As Object
    Set mailItem = outlookApp.CreateItem(0)
    
    Dim emailsList As String
    emailsList = Join(groupEmails, ";")
    
    With mailItem
        '.To =
        .CC = emailsList
        .Display
    End With
    
    
End Sub
```

Let me know if it works

Comment: Hi, I tested this code, but it didn't work property. I can create new email but only with last email address on the column. I can change group name on drop down list but I get the same result - last email on selected column. Could you modified the code?  I tried too pervious code from József Kökény but this time message will contain all address from the list but I will have about 40 contact list so it's very difficult to use numbers instead list names...

Comment: This solution prepares one email per email address in the group list. I don't understand your problem. The picture you're posting shows that the email address is the last one in the list but there should be 4 draft emails.

Comment: Maybe I wrong describe what I want. The final result should look like this (all address form column one by one in .CC email): https://ibb.co/rZWtXSG

Comment: Work perfectly, thank you so much!!! Now I will try implement this code to my project.

Answer (score 0):

Hello try this: put a drop-down list on Project sheet. Like this: [drop down list in Excel](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/09/24/excel-drop-down-list/)

[image]

and the code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub EmailCC()
    Dim xOTApp As Object
    Dim xMItem As Object
    Dim xCell As Range
    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xEmailAddr As String
    Dim xTxt As String
    Dim w As Workbook
    Dim sProject As Worksheet
    Dim sContacts As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim column  As Integer
    Set w = ActiveWorkbook
    Set sProject = w.Sheets(1)
    Set sContacts = w.Sheets(2)
    On Error Resume Next
    column = sProject.Cells(3, 9).Value
    If Not (IsNumeric(column)) Then Exit Sub
    Set xOTApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    i = 3
    Do While Not sContacts.Cells(i, column).Value = ""
                xEmailAddr = sContacts.Cells(i, column).Value & ";" & xEmailAddr
                i = i + 1
    Loop
    Set xMItem = xOTApp.CreateItem(0)
    With xMItem
        .To = " "
        .CC = xEmailAddr
        .Display
    End With
End Sub
```

[Excel file](https://mega.nz/file/gNEjxaLR#lpcCCKFdAw6STKOXX6DNITvpCyQuSw_wZ134kbK3Kbw)